# Problems running Firefox with Xvfb

Tags: firefox, selenium, centos, xvfb

**Required:** I'm trying to run headless selenium (using PHPUnit) on fresh CentOS 7 minimal.

**Problem:** It seems I installed everything correctly but firefox is not launching and my selenium web driver stuck at `14:45:31.646 INFO - Launching Firefox...`. With firefox command, I'm getting following output

`[admin@EE ~]$ /usr/bin/Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1024x768x24 &
[1] 11932
[admin@EE ~]$ export DISPLAY=:1
[admin@EE ~]$ firefox
firefox:11936): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1".
Fontconfig warning: ignoring UTF-8: not a valid region tag
console.error:
  [CustomizableUI]
  Custom widget with id loop-button does not return a valid node
console.error:
  [CustomizableUI]
  Custom widget with id loop-button does not return a valid node
GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.`

Selenium web driver stucks at `04:22:53.835 INFO - Launching Firefox...`

Can someone please suggest why selenium is not able to identify Firefox?

**Edit**

Comment: What is your current locale?

`locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=`

Comment: firefox latest 43 version having issue with selenium .. It already create issue everywhere.. https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1385

Comment: I am not sure but may it happen because of same.

Comment: My Firefox version is 38. `firefox -v
Mozilla Firefox 38.5.0`

Comment: @ShubhamJain I guess line `GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.` is issue but no idea how to fix it.

Comment: found out similer issue for ubuntu .. I m not sure, may be it related http://askubuntu.com/questions/558446/my-dconf-gsettings-installation-is-broken-how-can-i-fix-it-without-ubuntu-reins

Comment: What is your current locale?

Comment: @EtanReisner I updated output of `locale` command in question. There is some error as well but I do not understand if it have some impact. General locale is en_US

Comment: Yeah `LC_CTYPE=UTF-8` looks wrong to me. Try finding out what is setting that incorrectly and fix it and see if (at least some of) your problems go away.

Comment: I am having the same issue: Custom widget with id loop-button does not return a valid node. Works fine with Chrome, FF(version 38.7.1esr) reset, restart and re-install didn't help. Any suggestions?

Comment: Also upgrading to selenum 2.46 from 2.45 didn't help.